# Can I ReadLock a file while I create/modify it using System.IO.File.WriteAllText() method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, biztalk, streamwriter

I need to create a process that creates/modifies some text files in a folder. I am using below code to do that:

```
file = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);
file.Directory.Create(); 
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file.FullName, "Some text...");
```

I have a Biztalk queue that looks into the text files in the folder every 2 minutes and picks up the files to process them. I want to lock the files when I am creating/modifying so that Biztalk wont try to process those files. How can I achieve this?

I read about Transactional NTFS in windows which will let me create Transaction context but windows documentation says this feature will deprecated and recommends not to use it.

Comment: Steve, I tried creating a huge file and tried to open it in notepad when the file is still being written, I am able to open it. Doesn't this mean Biztalk should be able to read too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To acquire an exclusive lock you can use the file stream to do so

```
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Test.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("test");
            }
        }
```

This way you are locking the file exclusively for the current file stream. Any other application or even a new instance of file stream from another thread within the same application attempts to read or write to the file will be denied by the operating system.

Answer (score 3):

If the file is on a local NTFS volume of CIFS share, the File Adapter will not attempt to read an open file.  However,

A better pattern would be to do your file work in a temporary folder, then copy the completed files to the BizTalk folder only when they are done.  That way, you don't have to worry about locking at all.

Comment: Jhons, its a good solution but it would mean I have to write another component and that adds more complexity so going with Steve's option.

Comment: @Nitheesh Ok, but my option is far more common ;)  Why can't you just copy the file in the same process once you're done with it?  I do predict relying on locks will cause problems.  Been there, done that.

Comment: I have to write upto 500 files/sec which are of the size 700kb-1mb, I am thinking writing them to one place and copying them will impact the performance of the application.

Comment: @Nitheesh Use a move rather than a copy, if it is on the same drive all it does it updates the DIR entries.  The other option is to use a temporary filename (that does not match the file that BizTalk is expecting) and rename the file when you have finished writing it.

Comment: @Nitheesh Don't worry about 'performance' unless you can *prove* you need to.  Focus on reliability and maintainability.  Performance will not be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, write file with different extension then rename the file works fine.